# Separar una lista en "n" partes

Tags: python

Tengo una lista de 16 valores, quisiera saber como puedo separarla de la siguiente manera:

```
data= [1, 'PURECO', 'WOMAN', 'MARISCAL', 'MULLER', 28, 'DIABETES', 'APC', datetime.date(2020, 1, 3), 2, 'CAO', 'WOMAN', 'CAL Y MAYOR', 'URTIZ', 34, 'OBESIDAD TIPO 1', 'APC', datetime.date(2020, 1, 3]
```

Lista como deberia de quedarme, separandola por cada 9 elementos:

```
[(1, 'PURECO', 'WOMAN', 'MARISCAL', 'MULLER', 28, 'DIABETES', 'APC', datetime.date(2020, 1, 3)), (2, 'CAO', 'WOMAN', 'CAL Y MAYOR', 'URTIZ', 34, 'OBESIDAD TIPO 1', 'APC', datetime.date(2020, 1, 3))]
```

Intente lo siguiente pero solo obtuve una lista de listas y quisiera que fuese asi:

```
forma que debo de obetener: [(9 elementos), (9 elementos)]
forma que obtengo:          [[9 elementos],[9 elementos]]:
```

```
data = [data[i:i+9] for i in range(0, len(data),9)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = [tuple(data[i:i+9]) for i in range(0, len(data),9)]
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te pueden votar negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Comment: @RuslanLópez no necesita mucha explicación, Sólo corrigió el código agregandole `tuple`

Comment: @LucasDamian por eso necesita explicacion? que agrego? que hace lo que agrego? como soluciona el problema original?